# setup chef cookbook in existing python project

Tags: python, git, scrapy, chef-infra, cookbook

Working with `Scrapy`, I have a requirement to use [poise cookbook](https://github.com/poise/python) for extracting information about the collaborators of a particular `git repo`. The api documentation is provided [here](https://developer.github.com/v3/). With no prior knowledge of handling of cookbooks, I need some guidelines in setting up and integrating it into my `scrapy project`.

Comment: What does your 'Scrapy' project want to do? What code  have you actually tried? What results did you get? why do you need to use 'Poise cookbook'? You need to try it for yourself and get a 'feel' for code that 'works' or 'doesn't' but returns error messages.

Comment: @RyanVincent my `Scrapy` project extracts the `git repo` url from different web urls. The repo is then cloned to a directory on server. Now I want use the `cookbook` to achieve the latter..

Comment: The poise cookbook is intended to install/configure python on a server. It can help you get an uniform install for your project (python, pip modules, virtualenv if needed) but this has nothing to do with your code at all. Deploying your code/app which use github api will be the next step...